# Can the server administrator browse date of the hosting based KVM Virtualization?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6

The hosting in https://www.digitalocean.com/ is based KVM Virtualization.
If I purchase a their hosting , and upload private data, can the server administrator browse all my of date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course they can. Remember this one rule and everything will all make sense:

[image: You know it's true.]

It's true! There is no "cloud." There are only other people's computers. Yes, the provider may waffle and say that "we don't have a lot of insight" or "we can't login on your behalf", but that's all rather comforting half truths that don't tell the whole story. Unless you're using volume level encryption, and only you hold the encryption keys, your data is just lying on a disk and can be accessed with trivial effort.

Do not trust the cloud. The cloud hates you, hates your data, and probably kicks your dog when you're not looking.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to us. As a self-managed provider, what you choose to log is up to you. On our end your Droplet is kind of a black box to us, and we don't have a lot of insight since we're unable to log in on your behalf or access your server's contents, data, or internal logs.

This article can help you learn more about accessing your server logs:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-view-and-configure-linux-logs-on-ubuntu-and-centos

Comment: I'm a beginner about Linux, I don't know what is true

Comment: unless you encrypt your virtual disks, whoever has direct access to the hardware, can access your virtual drives and thus your data. Will a hosting provider do that? Not if they value their reputation. So unless you're planning something illegal, there's no reason to worry. much.

Comment: @dyasny Yes, the gulf between "can" and "will" is a single step of one mile. Ponder that. </philosoraptor>

Comment: @user828896 Digital Ocean is "unable" to access your data, only because their [privacy policy](https://www.digitalocean.com/legal/privacy/) says they will not do so. Unless, of course, law enforcement comes calling, then it's open season...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't hide anything from the ones who 0wn both the hardware and the software your VM runs on.

As a mitigating measure you can make accessing your data more difficult by ensuring encryption for data in transit and at rest, by using secure protocols such as https & scp instead of http & FTP and setting up encrypted volumes.

Selecting the right encryption (with ciphers that support [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy)) helps to mitigate the risk as well.

In reality you can only hope that simply nobody cares enough to about your data to make the effort, hope that the hosting company has enforced policies that prevent unauthorized curiosity by the staff and default settings that make that non-trivial as well and last that you are not suspected of doing anything that draws authorized scrutiny to your activities.